# MergeSort index

Tags: java, algorithm

I made a mergesort algorithm in java. It works, but it I don't know why.

Here's the problem:

```
for(int k = 0; k < r; k++)
```

If i write the for loop like that, the code will not work. However, if I change the 0 to "p-1", it will. The value of p is 1, which means that p-1 is 0. Why does p-1 work when 0 doesn't?

Here's the rest of my code:

```
public class MergeSort {


public static void main(String args[]){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i <array.length; i++){
        array[i] = rand.nextInt(11);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    mergeSort(array, 1, array.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
public static void merge(int[] A, int p, int q, int r){
    //
    //length of subarray 1
    int n1 = q-p+1;

    //length of subarray 2
    int n2 = r-q;

    int[] L = new int[n1+1];
    int[] R = new int[n2+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        L[i] = A[p+i-1];
    }

    for(int j=0; j< n2; j++){
        R[j] = A[q+j];
    }

    L[n1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    R[n2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(int k = p-1; k < r; k++){
        if(L[i] <= R[j]){
            A[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
                A[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
    }


}

public static void mergeSort(int[] A, int p, int r){
    if (p<r){
        int q = (int) Math.floor((r+p)/2);
        mergeSort(A, p, q);
        mergeSort(A, q+1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid one or two letter variable names unless it is very understandable. It makes code much harder to read.

Comment: this is a recursive function, you want to merge 2 list given the left and right index, it is not necessarily true that it will always begin from 0 as the same Array is being passed around.

Comment: @TameHog Sorry, I wrote this based on some pseudocode and just gave the variables the same names.

Comment: @Jesper it's fine just try to avoid when your asking a question

Comment: @Mox But the value of p is always 1, so p-1 will always be 0. How do you explain that it works with p-1 then?

Comment: @Jesper, refer to my answer below =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

and the code that you have provided

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] A, int p, int r){
    if (p<r){
        int q = (int) Math.floor((r+p)/2);
        mergeSort(A, p, q);
        mergeSort(A, q+1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}
```

Your list is partitioned into left and right sections each with different indices.
Therefore, in this particular example, you will get

mergeSort(A, 1, 5)

mergeSort(A, 6, 10)

For the first method call, it will be processing [**1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,** 7, 8, 9]

while the second method call, it will be processing [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, **7, 8, 9**]

These operations are performed on the same array. In the subsequent call of merge Sort in mergeSort(A, 6, 9)

you will get

mergeSort(A, 6, 7)
mergeSort(A, 8, 9)

You can see that your indices clearly doesn't start from 0. Therefore processing it from 0 will give you the wrong result.

Here is a nice resource for you to learn about merge sort developed by the University that I am currently studying in.

[visualgo-sorting](http://visualgo.net/sorting.html#)

Comment: First of all, when i change it to mergeSort(array, 0, array.length); I get an out of bound exception. Secondly, the code works when I try to run it with p-1, which is equal to zero. I don't understand why that works then?

Comment: because you assumed that you will always merge 2 list from 0, which is not true . this is a recursive code that partitions the array, therefore the value of p varies depending on the partition you are working on. imagine you are processing the array from index 5 to 9, setting the k=p will work, but k=0 is clearly wrong as 0 falls outside of the range.

Comment: one way to really understand what is actually happening is to sit down and write down each steps and see what is actually happening.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that p does actually change, my bad. Been sitting with this for way too long, guess i can't think clearly anymore. Thanks for your help. Regarding the mergeSort call in the main method, it should be called with the parameter 1, right? Because when i try to call it with 0, I get an exception.

Comment: you are getting the exception due to p-1 in your other methods. 0-1 = -1 which doesnt exist. so change your p-1 to p will solve the issue

Comment: yeah, I just noticed that you edited your comment, Thank you very much!

Comment: do mark it as correct answer if you found it useful. =)

Comment: I will! Just one more thing though, I changed the 1 in the main method call to 0 and the p-1 to p, but I still get an exception. Any idea why?

Comment: to A[p+i]; ? If I do that, it doesn't sort them correctly anymore.

Comment: ok i realized that, this version have to be p-1 and start from 1. else it will require more changes to another way of merging.